# Squid Proxy Server Error : Upon Starting

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, ubuntu-18.04, slackware

I got this error upon starting Squid Proxy Server using the command `sudo squid -z`

```
fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open(/squid-cf__metadata.shm): 13 permission denied
```

How shall I fix it? Im using version 3.5.26 of Squid. I tried any fixes I found in the web but nothing works.

I tried implementing the fix below I found in the web:

```
Just add the following line to your /etc/fstab file: 
shm /dev/shm tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0 
After that use (as root): 
# mount shm
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Another possible fix on the web is error reading squid.pid

```
squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file
/var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
```

Unfortunately, as I look in my directory, I could not find `squid.pid`.

How will I get my Squid working? Thanks.

Comment: Something's wrong with your permissions in `/dev/shm`, but the permissions in fstab should be okay. Do you have SElinux enabled? If yes, then disable it for testing. Please add the output of `ls -la /dev/shm`.

Comment: Could you include more info, please? OS and the squid.conf file could be helpful

Comment: How did you install squid? Current version for Ubuntu 18.04 is 3.5.27. Please apply updates. And did you try starting squid from its startup script with `systemctl start squid`?

Answer (score 1):

You've run `squid` with the wrong user, which created files with wrong permissions.

> squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file

You need to run with `sudo`: `sudo squid -z`.

> fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open(/squid-cf__metadata.shm): 13 permission denied

You need to remove Squid's `.shm` files from `/dev/shm` or assign the right permissions.

```
$ sudo rm -v /dev/shm/squid*.shm
```

Also make sure that:

- Squid's log dir (`/var/log/squid`?) is owned by the right user (`proxy`?).
- Squid's cache dir (`/var/spool/squid`?) is owned by the right user.

For the full example, check the following Docker container at [`sameersbn/docker-squid`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid).

Comment: This took me to the right direction, but what really solved the problem in my case (using Ubuntu Jammy) was: chmod 777 /dev/shm

Answer (score 0):

According [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/squid-not-working-493802) add following configurations to `/etc/squid/squid.conf`

```
cache_effective_user nobody
cache_effective_group nobody
```